# How to get users' ip address by java?

Tags: java, ip

As we java developer known, it's generally we get users' ip address by following codes.My question is, by this way, what we get is LAN ip or WAN ip. if two users are from the same LAN, what we get is two different LAN ip or one the same WAN ip.

```
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    log.info("X-Forwarded-For: {}", ip);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ip) || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("X-Real-IP");
        log.info("X-Real-IP: {}", ip);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ip) || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("Cdn-Src-Ip");
        log.info("Cdn-Src-Ip: {}", ip);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ip) || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
        log.info("Proxy-Client-IP: {}", ip);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ip) || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
        log.info("WL-Proxy-Client-IP: {}", ip);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ip) || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        log.info("RemoteAddr: {}", ip);
    }
```

Functions what I'm developing need to distinguish users, so I have to make sure the ip I get from different users is unique whether they are from same LAN or different LAN.Please info me if you understand it.

Comment: If you want a unique identifier for a user, just *ask for that*, and not how to get a user's IP, which is clearly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Internal LAN addresses are never available from the outside world. That's because NAT transforms these into the WAN address and vice versa. For the outside world only one IP address is available for everybody inside the LAN. That can indeed lead to issues like throttling if only the IP address is used, especially for large LANs, which you often see at companies.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address of a normal user is not fixed and may change in a short time, so I think there are some problems in using IP address to limit, MAC address should be better, but the web side can not obtain.
Secondly, under normal circumstances, only LANIp or WANIp can be obtained, and most of the same router will have only one public IP and it is still variable.